# Confirm password using jquery rules not working

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, jquery-validate, password-confirmation

I need to get the same password in cpassword. But here although the passwords match it gives error that the password do not match. When I remove the rule of equalTo the methods works fine.

So I think the problem is with ,cpassword'

```js
rules: {
    password: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 8,
      remote: {
        url: baseURL + "member/checkPassword1",
        type: "post",
        data: {
          action: function() {
            return "checkPassword1";
          }
        }
      }
    },
    cpassword: {
      required: true,
      equalTo: "#password"
    }
  },
  messages: {
    password: {
      required: "Please enter the password!",
      minlength: "Password should contain at least 8 character!"
    },
    cpassword: {
      required: "Please confirm the password!",
      equalTo: "Confirm password doesn't match the Password"
    }
  },
```

**view**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="headlabel"><?=$this->lang->line("Password");?><strong>*</strong></label>
    <input class="formtext form-control" type="password" name="password" id="password" value="<?php echo set_value('password'); ?>" onkeypress="removeerror('password')" placeholder=" <?=$this->lang->line("Enter_your_passwrd");?> ">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove right errorcross" id="password_cross" style=""></span>
    <label class="errorlabel" id="password_error"><?php echo form_error('password'); ?></label>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="headlabel"><?=$this->lang->line("Confirm_password");?><strong>*</strong></label>
    <input class="formtext form-control" type="password" name="cpassword" id="cpassword1" value="<?php echo set_value('cpassword'); ?>" onkeypress="removeerror('cpassword')" placeholder=" <?=$this->lang->line("Retype_your_passsword");?> ">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove right errorcross" id="cpassword_cross" style=""></span>
    <label class="errorlabel" id="cpassword_error"><?php echo form_error('cpassword'); ?></label>
</div>
```

Does anyone have any idea on this? How can I correct it?

Comment: Which jquery library you are using ?

Comment: Im not sure on how to check it. But there is a validation same as this for another form in the same js file and it works perfectly.

Comment: Can you check in the html is there anywhere same id's are repeating?

Comment: I checked. Those id's are not repeating.

Comment: Show the ***rendered*** HTML markup as seen by the client-side code.

Comment: Try removing the inline `onkeypress` handlers from your input elements.  Inline JavaScript is not needed when you use jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your HTML for cpassword input element add `data-rule-equalto='#password'` property and have a check

Comment: https://johnnycode.com/2014/03/27/using-jquery-validate-plugin-html5-data-attribute-rules/

Comment: Then it gives an error "Please enter the same value again." although I enter the same value.

Comment: update the change password  id to different ID and have a check . some time keywords will create a problem not sure in your scenario

Comment: can we have jsfiddle link ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180432/discussion-between-shavindi-pathirana-and-suresh).